# Google-colaboratory: "Connection aborted.', OSError (0, 'Error')"

Tags: python, optimization, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to run a CNN optimization process (the whole process takes an average of 4 hours), on the Google Colab platform, using the support of a GPU. However, at approximately 2, 2.5 hours of training, Colab simply locks (interrupts the training season). I think that the problem is not in code, because it works if I limit de search space from the optimizer.

The whole code that I'm using is:

```
# General modeling in the dataset:
!pip install pandas
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
import random as python_random
import scipy.io
import time
import datetime
from numpy import array
from decimal import Decimal
from numpy import savetxt
 
# Data pre-processing (sample standardization):
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
 
# Conversion of vectors into a binary class matrix:
from keras.utils import to_categorical
 
# Indexing of samples for training, validation and test:
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
 
# Neural network architecture (powered by TensorFlow and Keras):
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import load_model
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks import *
from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers import *
 
# Confusion matrix:
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import itertools
 
# Plotting tools:
!pip install matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import pyplot
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model
 
# TensorDash (metrics check by smartphone app):
!pip install tensor-dash
from tensordash.tensordash import Tensordash

# Módulo de importação de dados a partir do Google Drive:
from google.colab import drive
# Montando o Google Drive na máquina virtual do Colaboratory:
drive.mount('/content/drive')
 
# Importação do dataset de corrente dos computadores:
path = '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Dataset/'
path = path + "pcs_B_dataset.csv"
 
allData  = pd.read_csv(path, delimiter=';')
 
# Transformação do dataframe em array:
data = np.asarray(allData)
data1 = data.astype(np.float)
 
# Verificação do shape requerido:
print('\nThe matrix shape is:',data1.shape)

# FUNÇÃO QUE FAZ O SUBSET E PREPARAÇÃO DO BANCO DE DADOS:
def subsetA(cases_num):
  '''
  cases_num: qtde. de casos que se deseja manter;
  Retorna os inputs de treinamento/validação/teste para a CNN;
  Preparação dos dados como sugerido pelo prof. Leonardo;
  A rejeição dos casos é feita antes da preparação dos dados para a CNN
  simulando uma situação real de coleta de poucas amostras/casos.'
  '''

  n_cases = cases_num  # Armazena a qtde. de casos utilizada para insights mais
                       # à frente.
  
  # Faz o fatiamento dos dados de acordo com a qtde. de casos requerida:
  data_red = data1[:(1666*cases_num)]


  # Definição de parâmetros iniciais para o processamento do dataframe:
  NUM_CASES = cases_num            # Nº de casos.
  NUM_CLASSES = 16                 # Nº de combinações.
  NUM_SAMPLES = 1666               # Nº de amostras/caso.


  # Criando os rótulos:
  allLabels = np.zeros(NUM_CASES)  # Cria um array contendo 0s, com o shape (1, qtde. de casos).
  ones = np.ones(NUM_CASES)        # Cria um array contendo 1s, com o shape (1, qtde. de casos).

  for i in range(1,NUM_CLASSES):
    labels = i * ones                          # Shape fica (1, qtde. de casos).
    allLabels = np.vstack((allLabels, labels)) # Empilha os vetores e o shape fica (16, qtde. de casos).

  Y = allLabels # 'Y' assume a rotulagem e o shape (16, qtde. de casos).

  # Reshape para padronização dos dados:
  data = data_red.reshape(-1,NUM_SAMPLES)      # Data agora assume o shape (qtde. TOTAL de casos, 1666)
  # (O '-1' no índice escolhido força os dados a se adequarem ao reshape solicitado de acordo com o outro índice)

  # Padronização dos dados
  #Com o método StandardScaler:
  #(Transforma os dados para média zero e desvio padrão igual a um)
  scaler = StandardScaler()
  data_normal = scaler.fit_transform(data)

  X = data_normal                          # 'X' assume os dados das amostras e o shape (qtde. TOTAL de casos,1666).
  Y = allLabels.flatten()                  # Os rótulos são 'achatados' para uma linha com shape (1, qtde. TOTAL de casos).
  Y = to_categorical(Y)                    # Converte o vetor de classe (inteiros) em matriz de classe binária.
  X = X.reshape(X.shape[0],X.shape[1],1)   # 'X' é formatado para o shape (qtde. TOTAL de casos,1666,1), forçando a 3ª dim. exigida pela rede.


  # Separação das amostras de treinamento, validação e teste:
  # Indexação de 20% para TESTE:
  X_train_val, X_test, Y_train_val, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)
  # Do TREINAMENTO, indexa 20% para VALIDAÇÃO:
  X_train, X_val, Y_train, Y_val = train_test_split(X_train_val, Y_train_val, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)
  
  return X_train, Y_train, X_val, Y_val, X_test, Y_test, n_cases

# TensorDash (acompanhamento das métricas do modelo pelo app Android):
histories = Tensordash(ModelName = 'HARES', email = 'viniciuswv@gmail.com',
                       password = 'admin1')

# Batch size (número de exemplos de treinamento usados em uma iteração/época):
batch_size = 32
# Épocas (quantidade de ciclos de treinamento da rede neural):
epochs = 500


# FUNÇÃO QUE CRIA A CNN:
def create_model():
  'Retorna o objeto (modelo), que estará sujeita à fitness function;'
  'Arquitetura nº 3, exatamente como implementada em (FIRMES, 2020).'

  inputs = Input((1666,1))

  Conv = Conv1D(32, kernel_size=4, strides=1, activation='relu', padding='same')(inputs)
  Conv = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=3, strides=None, padding='valid')(Conv)
  Conv = BatchNormalization()(Conv)
  
  Conv = Conv1D(64, kernel_size=4, strides=1, activation='relu', padding='same')(Conv)
  Conv = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=3, strides=None, padding='valid')(Conv)
  Conv = BatchNormalization()(Conv)
  
  Conv = Conv1D(128, kernel_size=4, strides=1, activation='relu', padding='same')(Conv)
  Conv = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=3, strides=None, padding='valid')(Conv)
  Conv = BatchNormalization()(Conv)
  
  Conv = Conv1D(256, kernel_size=4, strides=1, activation='relu', padding='same')(Conv)
  Conv = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=3, strides=None, padding='valid')(Conv)
  Conv = BatchNormalization()(Conv)
  
  flat = Flatten()(Conv)
  
  dense = Dense(512, activation='relu')(flat)
  dense = Dense(256, activation='relu')(dense)
  dense = Dense(128, activation='relu')(dense)
  dense = Dense(16, activation='softmax')(dense)
  model = Model(inputs, dense)

  model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                optimizer='SGD',
                metrics=['accuracy'])

  return model

# Criação do modelo e verificação de seu sumário:
model = create_model()  

# Salvando o modelo e os pesos não treinados como referência para o looping:
save_path = '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/PCs saved model/'

model.save(save_path,
           include_optimizer = True,
           overwrite = True,
           save_format = 'tf')

def fit_model(model, X_train, Y_train, X_val, Y_val, batch_size, epochs):
  'Recebe o modelo e as novas amostras (sucessivamente reduzidas).'
  'Retorna o modelo (treinado/validado), history, e o máximo valor de val_accuracy.'
  
  # Reinicia a sessão do Keras, evitando sobrecarregamento de memória:
  tf.keras.backend.clear_session()

  start_time = time.time()         # Parâmetro para tempo de treinamento.
  
  # Método ".fit()" do Keras:
  history = model.fit(X_train,
                      Y_train,
                      batch_size = batch_size,
                      epochs = epochs,
                      verbose = 1,
                      validation_data = (X_val, Y_val),
                      callbacks = [histories])
   
  accuracy = history.history['val_accuracy']
  trainAcc = history.history['accuracy']
 
  acc_max = max(accuracy)           # Armazena a maior val_accuracy da lista.

# Calculando o índice de estabilidade da rede, MDBA (Mean of Difference Between Accuracies):
  trainAcc1 = np.asarray(trainAcc) # Transforma a lista de acurácias de treinamento em array para facilitar operações aritméticas.
  validAcc1 = np.asarray(accuracy) # Transforma a lista de acurácias de validação em array.

  diff = (trainAcc1 - validAcc1) # Subtrai, item a item, um array pelo outro.
  meanDiff = np.mean(diff) # Calcula a média das diferenças. Quanto menor, melhor (mais estável a rede se comportou).
  
  MDBA = meanDiff.tolist()
 
  end_time = time.time()            # Parâmetro para tempo de treinamento.
 
  # Visualização do tempo total de treinamento:
  print("Training/validation time was: %g seconds" % (end_time - start_time))

  train_time = (end_time - start_time)
 
  return model, history, acc_max, train_time, MDBA

def test_model(X_test, Y_test, model):
  'Recebe as novas amostras de teste (X, Y), assim como o novo modelo gerado.'
  'Retorna a acurácia de teste (é o parâmetro para continuar iterando).'
  
  print('\n',
        '\nEVALUATING THE MODEL:')
  
  start_time = time.time()
 
  scores = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=1, return_dict=False)
 
  end_time = time.time()
 
  print("Evaluate time was %g seconds" % (end_time - start_time))
 
  test_accuracy = (scores[1])  # Armazena apenas a acurácia do teste.
  
  print(test_accuracy)
 
  return test_accuracy

def fitness():
  'Reduz casos até que a acurácia de teste atinja um valor pré determinado.'
  'Retorna o melhor modelo, históricos de fitness e redução de casos.'
 
  acc_target = 0.90  # Qual a acurácia de teste alvo? (0.01:1).
  cases = 625        # Preencher com (600 + decrease step value utilizado).
  fitness = 1    # Fitness inicia em 0.999 (acc encontrada em FIRMES, 2020).
  fitness_hist = []
  n_cases_hist = []
  acc_val_hist = []
  acc_test_hist = []
  time_hist = []
  MDBA_hist = []
 
  while fitness > acc_target:
    cases = cases - 25  # Decrease step value (passo da redução de casos).

    # Faz o subset das amostras (escolher entre o 'random_subset', 'subsetA' ou 'subsetB'):
    X_train_new, Y_train_new, X_val_new, Y_val_new, X_test_new, Y_test_new, n_cases = subsetA(cases)
 
    # Carrega o modelo salvo:
    model = load_model(save_path)

    print('\n---> ITERATING NOW WITH:',n_cases,'CASES !',
          '(',"%.2f" % round((((n_cases)/600)*100),2),'% FROM TOTAL )',
          '\n----> AND THE HISTORY OF CASES DECREASE IS:',n_cases_hist,
          '\n',
          '\nTRAINING AND VALIDATING THE MODEL:')
    
    # Treina o modelo com as novas amostras (agrega as funções 'subset' e 'model'):
    model2, history, acc_max, train_time, MDBA = fit_model(model, X_train_new, Y_train_new, X_val_new, Y_val_new, batch_size, epochs)

    # Testa o modelo com as novas amostras:
    test_accuracy = test_model(X_test_new, Y_test_new, model2)

    print('\nSUMMARY:',
          '\nWith',n_cases,'cases, the max val_accuracy was:',
          "%.4f" % round((acc_max*100),4),'% and the test_accuracy was:',
          "%.4f" % round((test_accuracy*100),4),'%.',
          '\nIt is a difference of',
          "%.4f" % round(((acc_max*100)-(test_accuracy*100)),4),'%.')
    
    n_cases_hist.append(n_cases) # Armazena o histórico de redução de casos.
    fitness_hist.append(fitness) # Armazena o histórico de fitness.
    acc_val_hist.append(acc_max) # Armazena o histórico da acurácia de validação.
    acc_test_hist.append(test_accuracy) # Armazena o histórico da acurácia de teste.
    time_hist.append(train_time) # Armazena os tempos gastos nos treinamentos.
    MDBA_hist.append(MDBA) # Armazena o histórico de MDBA.

    print('Fitness history is:', fitness_hist)
    print('Cases history is:', n_cases_hist)
    print('acc_val history is:', acc_val_hist)
    print('acc_test history is:', acc_test_hist)
    print('Times history is:', time_hist)
    print('MDBA history is:', MDBA_hist)
 
    # Fitness reduz em função da redução da acurácia de teste:
    if test_accuracy < fitness:
      fitness = test_accuracy # Fitness assume o valor da nova acurácia de teste.
           
    # Apaga os modelos (pois suas informações podem persistir no estado geral):
    del model
    # Reinicia a sessão do Keras, evitando sobrecarregamento de memória:
    K.clear_session()
    tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
    tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph()
      
  print('\nHILL CLIMBING: For the configured step, was possible to reduce the dataset to',
        n_cases_hist[-1],'cases, with test_accuracy of',fitness_hist[-1])
 
  return model2, history, fitness_hist, n_cases_hist, acc_val_hist, acc_test_hist, time_hist, acc_target, MDBA_hist

# Execução da fitness function:
model2, history, fitness_hist, n_cases_hist, acc_val_hist, acc_test_hist, time_hist, acc_target, MDBA_hist = fitness()
 
print('\nThe fitness history is:',fitness_hist,
      '\nThe cases decrease history is:',n_cases_hist)
```

After the error, Colabs provides the following feedback:

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    599                                                   body=body, headers=headers,
--> 600                                                   chunked=chunked)
    601 

33 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    342         try:
--> 343             self._validate_conn(conn)
    344         except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError) as e:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _validate_conn(self, conn)
    838         if not getattr(conn, 'sock', None):  # AppEngine might not have  `.sock`
--> 839             conn.connect()
    840 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py in connect(self)
    343             server_hostname=server_hostname,
--> 344             ssl_context=context)
    345 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py in ssl_wrap_socket(sock, keyfile, certfile, cert_reqs, ca_certs, server_hostname, ssl_version, ciphers, ssl_context, ca_cert_dir)
    344         if HAS_SNI and server_hostname is not None:
--> 345             return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
    346 

/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py in wrap_socket(self, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname, session)
    406                          server_hostname=server_hostname,
--> 407                          _context=self, _session=session)
    408 

/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py in __init__(self, sock, keyfile, certfile, server_side, cert_reqs, ssl_version, ca_certs, do_handshake_on_connect, family, type, proto, fileno, suppress_ragged_eofs, npn_protocols, ciphers, server_hostname, _context, _session)
    816                         raise ValueError("do_handshake_on_connect should not be specified for non-blocking sockets")
--> 817                     self.do_handshake()
    818 

/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py in do_handshake(self, block)
   1076                 self.settimeout(None)
-> 1077             self._sslobj.do_handshake()
   1078         finally:

/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py in do_handshake(self)
    688         """Start the SSL/TLS handshake."""
--> 689         self._sslobj.do_handshake()
    690         if self.context.check_hostname:

OSError: [Errno 0] Error


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ProtocolError                             Traceback (most recent call last)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    448                     retries=self.max_retries,
--> 449                     timeout=timeout
    450                 )

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    637             retries = retries.increment(method, url, error=e, _pool=self,
--> 638                                         _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
    639             retries.sleep()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py in increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
    367             if read is False or not self._is_method_retryable(method):
--> 368                 raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
    369             elif read is not None:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py in reraise(tp, value, tb)
    684         if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
--> 685             raise value.with_traceback(tb)
    686         raise value

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    599                                                   body=body, headers=headers,
--> 600                                                   chunked=chunked)
    601 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    342         try:
--> 343             self._validate_conn(conn)
    344         except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError) as e:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _validate_conn(self, conn)
    838         if not getattr(conn, 'sock', None):  # AppEngine might not have  `.sock`
--> 839             conn.connect()
    840 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py in connect(self)
    343             server_hostname=server_hostname,
--> 344             ssl_context=context)
    345 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py in ssl_wrap_socket(sock, keyfile, certfile, cert_reqs, ca_certs, server_hostname, ssl_version, ciphers, ssl_context, ca_cert_dir)
    344         if HAS_SNI and server_hostname is not None:
--> 345             return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
    346 

/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py in wrap_socket(self, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname, session)
    406                          server_hostname=server_hostname,
--> 407                          _context=self, _session=session)
    408 

/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py in __init__(self, sock, keyfile, certfile, server_side, cert_reqs, ssl_version, ca_certs, do_handshake_on_connect, family, type, proto, fileno, suppress_ragged_eofs, npn_protocols, ciphers, server_hostname, _context, _session)
    816                         raise ValueError("do_handshake_on_connect should not be specified for non-blocking sockets")
--> 817                     self.do_handshake()
    818 

/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py in do_handshake(self, block)
   1076                 self.settimeout(None)
-> 1077             self._sslobj.do_handshake()
   1078         finally:

/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py in do_handshake(self)
    688         """Start the SSL/TLS handshake."""
--> 689         self._sslobj.do_handshake()
    690         if self.context.check_hostname:

ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', OSError(0, 'Error'))


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ConnectionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-9-3b9b0bf4bede> in <module>()
      1 # Execução da fitness function:
----> 2 model2, history, fitness_hist, n_cases_hist, acc_val_hist, acc_test_hist, time_hist, acc_target, MDBA_hist = fitness()
      3 
      4 print('\nThe fitness history is:',fitness_hist,
      5       '\nThe cases decrease history is:',n_cases_hist)

<ipython-input-8-15b3c6593366> in fitness()
     30 
     31     # Treina o modelo com as novas amostras (agrega as funções 'subset' e 'model'):
---> 32     model2, history, acc_max, train_time, MDBA = fit_model(model, X_train_new, Y_train_new, X_val_new, Y_val_new, batch_size, epochs)
     33 
     34     # Testa o modelo com as novas amostras:

<ipython-input-6-ac63f6e4836d> in fit_model(model, X_train, Y_train, X_val, Y_val, batch_size, epochs)
     16                       verbose = 1,
     17                       validation_data = (X_val, Y_val),
---> 18                       callbacks = [histories])
     19 
     20   accuracy = history.history['val_accuracy']

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    106   def _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
    107     if not self._in_multi_worker_mode():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 108       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    109 
    110     # Running inside `run_distribute_coordinator` already.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1135           epoch_logs.update(val_logs)
   1136 
-> 1137         callbacks.on_epoch_end(epoch, epoch_logs)
   1138         training_logs = epoch_logs
   1139         if self.stop_training:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py in on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs)
    414         if numpy_logs is None:  # Only convert once.
    415           numpy_logs = tf_utils.to_numpy_or_python_type(logs)
--> 416         callback.on_epoch_end(epoch, numpy_logs)
    417 
    418   def on_train_batch_begin(self, batch, logs=None):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensordash/tensordash.py in on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs)
    140         values = [epoch, self.loss, self.acc, self.val_loss, self.val_acc]
    141         self.epoch_num = epoch + 1
--> 142         SendData.sendMessage(key = self.key, auth_token = self.auth_token, params = values, ModelName = self.ModelName)
    143 
    144     def on_train_end(self, epoch, logs = {}):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensordash/tensordash.py in sendMessage(self, key, auth_token, params, ModelName)
     52             data = '{"Epoch":' +  str(epoch+1) + ', "Loss" :' + str(loss) + ', "Accuracy" :' + str(acc) + ', "Validation Loss":' + str(val_loss) + ', "Validation Accuracy" :' + str(val_acc) + '}'
     53 
---> 54         response = requests.post('https://cofeeshop-tensorflow.firebaseio.com/user_data/{}/{}.json'.format(key, ModelName), params = auth_token, data=data)
     55 
     56     def model_init(self, key = None, auth_token = None, ModelName = 'Sample Model'):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/api.py in post(url, data, json, **kwargs)
    117     """
    118 
--> 119     return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
    120 
    121 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/api.py in request(method, url, **kwargs)
     59     # cases, and look like a memory leak in others.
     60     with sessions.Session() as session:
---> 61         return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
     62 
     63 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    528         }
    529         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 530         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    531 
    532         return resp

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    641 
    642         # Send the request
--> 643         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    644 
    645         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    496 
    497         except (ProtocolError, socket.error) as err:
--> 498             raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
    499 
    500         except MaxRetryError as e:

ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', OSError(0, 'Error'))
```

Sometimes this error occurs earlier, sometimes later. I have already checked the stability of the internet, the minimum settings on my computer, I have tried to wait a few days for a new execution (I know the availability limitations of VMs), I have tested it in browsers (Chrome, Firefox and MS Edge), I have already followed the training (for the server do not shutdown, due to inactivity), however, nothing worked and I am not able to identify the source of the problem.

I would like someone to guide me in a possible solution.

Comment: How big is the dataset and are you utilising the option for more RAM?

Comment: The dataset have aproximately 150 Mb. And I'm not using the option for more RAM. However, during the tests, the RAM bar remains low, I think because the keras model is not storing the parameters changes from one model to another.

Comment: Please share a self-contained notebook that reproduces the problem you observe.

Comment: Hi @BobSmith, I did an update with the notebook that I'm using.